# Console logging an array of previously added inputs results in repeating last console log

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm following a web development course and I'm in a challenge in which I should be able to store a title and a body for a blog in an object inside an array on my server (app.js), and then log it in the console, however, every time I add a new post, the console logs an array of the previous posts and just then an updated array with all the posts, including the last one. I need to log only the updated array with all the posts.

PS: Sorry if its a bad explanation I just don't know how to put it into words

**app.js code**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam";
const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus";
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices.";

const app = express();

let newPosts = [];

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {
    homeStartingContent: homeStartingContent
  });
  console.log(newPosts);


});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about", {
    aboutStartingContent: aboutContent
  });
});

app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact", {
    contactStartingContent: contactContent
  });
});


app.post("/compose", (req, res) => {
  const post = {
    title: req.body.inputTitle,
    body: req.body.inputPost
  };
  newPosts.push(post);

  res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/compose", (req, res) => {
  res.render("compose");
});









app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

**compose.ejs code**

```
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>

<h1>Compose</h1>
<form action="/compose" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="composeTitle">Title</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="inputTitle">
    <label for="composePost">Post</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="inputPost" rows="5" cols="200"></textarea>

  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Publish</button>

</form>


<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

[image: What I'm getting in the console (first the last version of the array and then the updated array)]

I should be getting:

```
Server started on port 3000
[ { title: '1st post', body: 'This is my first post' } ]
[
  { title: '1st post', body: 'This is my first post' },
  { title: '2nd post', body: 'This is my second post' }
]
```

Comment: This problem is solved if I console log inside the post method of the "/compose" page, however I'm supposed to console log inside the get method of the "/" page